# Parse cloude function http request not working

Tags: javascript, curl, parse-platform

I have tried the follows code with curl but its now working, please have a look, thanks

Function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success('Hello world!');
});
```

Curl URL:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxx" [http][xxx]/parse/functions/hello
```

Error:

```
Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'runRequestListener' of undefined
at handleRequest (http.js:551:11)
at Parse.Cloud._runCustomEndpoint (<anonymous>:204:7)
```

Comment: is it mandatory that I should login for executing cloud code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

The problem is URL.
I thought the URL is our domain name but it's a parse API, As follows CURL request working fine.

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxx" [https][api.parse.com]/1/functions/hello
```

Comment: You know that they won't be in service for longer than January 2017, right? So you should be really using your own instance instead of their infrastructure.

Comment: Yes, I know, Migration is in the process. Thanks @mistapink